Help to understand Chutney
I'm trying to perform some experiments with chutney, it actually works fine, but I have some questions about I can use it for my scope. In particular, I want (first of all) discover the path that my package do through the tor network (node by node). I tried to send data with curl and in particular curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9000 www.torproject.org and I capture the output via Wireshark, I notice that the traffic pass through wlan0 (my wlan) and nothing pass on loopback, another thing that I notice is that on Wireshark the get request come from an IP that isn't mine, and I don't understand why. Continuing, since I want to see the package through the tor network, I decided to create an http server on 127.0.0.1:12058 with python python3 -m http.server 12058 and I sent a request via curl again curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9000 127.0.0.1:12058, now the traffic pass through loopback, but I can't follow the package because the Ips of client, realys and exit are the same 127.0.0.1 and what change is the port. From what I know, there exists 4 types of port:

ControlPort that can be used with nyx or other tool to control the       traffic
OrPort that is used by the nodes to send packets
DirPort that is used by AD to send informations such as consensus
SockPort used by the client to connect to the network

Standing on these informations, when I send a request to my http server I might see a lot of 127.0.0.1 that communicates each other with 9000 (sockport) for the client, orports for the relays and the exit node and the dirport for the DA, but what I see is different, infact the ports seems to be random and different from the ones wrote on the torrc (something like: 41126 or 34450) so I cannot follow the package.
Do you know why? Do you know how can I follow the package through the network? (maybe another tool or something like that) Am I doing something wrong?

First of all - you can not see the exit node's IP in your WireShark: it's encapsulated inside a 3-layered "onion". What you can see is:

A guard node(s) that are used to Enter Tor network by your tor instance
A nodes used for p2p connect for a first hop to make an onion pipe
Directories you're talking to for Tor's consensus
Other Tor nodes that are getting your directory mirror data - you SHOULD do it if you can forward a port or open one, it really helps the network

Yes - sometimes in a very rare case - you can see the connection to the node that is also an exit node you've used but it's a node-to node connection, not your exit one unless you have enabled a single-hop circuits. SHC's are gravely bad for privacy - use them as a last resort option!
127.0.0.1-stuff is how your software interacting with Tor as with any other SOCKS5s/SOCKS5h proxy. Don't use it as just SOCKS5 one - or you will need to use Tor's DNS port too and it's a potential DNS leak place unless it's properly handled by your firewall rules.
